# What's the best way to store a large array in Python such that the bytecode obtained after running py_compile.compile is as short as possible?

Tags: python

I have a list of 1000+ entries each of which is a list of 50+ entries and I need the byte code to be as short as possible. Storing the array in a separate file and loading it isn't possible, it must be in the code. It is definitely the limiting factor in size. It doesn't need to be a list, just searchable/iterable. I have a function that calculates idx and then I jump to count[idx] so I also need it to be ordered at some point.

Comment: If you need to embed it a source convert it to a byte string and decode on import, assuming RAM is not limiting factor.